Rendering font in pycairo does not reflect alpha value of font
I tried to render font using freetype-py and pycairo, but the font does not display it's alpha value in some case.
I made font bitmap using freetype-py and made image surface based on that bitmap using numpy and render it using pycairo.
It seems to render font in white background, but when I tried to render font on image or another pycairo shape, font does not reflect it's alpha value and rendered as rectangle.
This is the image with error.
pycairo image
And this is the simplified version of font rendering code. It does not contain rendering another shape in pycairo.
import cairo
import freetype
import numpy as np

# Set freetype constants
FT_LOAD_DEFAULT = freetype.FT_LOAD_FLAGS["FT_LOAD_DEFAULT"]
FT_LOAD_NO_BITMAP = freetype.FT_LOAD_FLAGS["FT_LOAD_NO_BITMAP"]

FT_RENDER_MODE_NORMAL = freetype.FT_RENDER_MODES["FT_RENDER_MODE_NORMAL"]

previous_char = None
previous_pos = [100, 100]

# Set font face
font_path = "some font name"
face = freetype.Face(font_path)
face.set_char_size(200 * 64)
base_to_top = face.size.ascender >> 6

font_color = [255, 0, 0]  # red

surface = cairo.ImageSurface(cairo.FORMAT_ARGB32, 1920, 1080)
context = cairo.Context(surface)

for char in "Hello world!":
    # create text bitmap
    face.load_char(char, FT_LOAD_DEFAULT | FT_LOAD_NO_BITMAP)
    slot = face.glyph
    glyph = slot.get_glyph()

    text_bitmap_glyph = glyph.to_bitmap(FT_RENDER_MODE_NORMAL, freetype.Vector(0, 0))
    text_bitmap = text_bitmap_glyph.bitmap

    if char == " ":
        text_array = np.zeros((base_to_top, slot.advance.x >> 6), dtype=np.uint8)
    else:
        text_array = np.array(text_bitmap.buffer, dtype=np.uint8).reshape(
            (text_bitmap.rows, text_bitmap.width)
        )

    # create text image, and set font color and alpha value
    text_image = np.zeros((text_array.shape[0], text_array.shape[1], 4), dtype=np.uint8)
    text_image[:, :, 0] = font_color[2]  # b
    text_image[:, :, 1] = font_color[1]  # g
    text_image[:, :, 2] = font_color[0]  # r
    text_image[:, :, 3] = text_array  # a

    # create image surface from text image
    text_surface = cairo.ImageSurface.create_for_data(
        text_image.data,
        cairo.FORMAT_ARGB32,
        text_image.shape[1],
        text_image.shape[0],
        text_image.strides[0],
    )

    text_pos_x = previous_pos[0] + slot.bitmap_left
    text_pos_y = (
        previous_pos[1] - slot.bitmap_top
        if char != " "
        else previous_pos[1] - base_to_top
    )

    # draw text image on the surface
    context.set_source_surface(text_surface, text_pos_x, text_pos_y)
    context.paint()

    previous_pos[0] += slot.advance.x >> 6
    if previous_char is not None:
        kerning = face.get_kerning(previous_char, char)
        previous_pos[1] += kerning.x >> 6

context.set_source_surface(surface)

